# Finding extremum of derivative of a function from the graph of the function.

Tags: derivatives, graphing-functions

In general, I want to know if it is possible to know if an extremum exists for the derivative of a function just by looking at the graph of the function.

As a specific problem, I want to be able to predict that there will be a maximum possible force caused by [Lennard-Jones potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lennard-Jones_potential).

Lennard-Jones potential is  $y=x^{-12}-x^{-6}$ shown in orange, and the negative of its derivative (force due to this potential), $y'=12 x^{-13}-6 x^{-7}$ is in blue.

[image]

Comment: In general you almost always have access to a finite picture of the function so you can't say for sure, however if you happen to eyeball an inflection point, then you know your function's derivative has a local extrema. In you example, the (orange) function looks continuous enough, and starts decreasing but later increases. So there must be an inflection point somewhere in the middle. That corresponds to an extrema for the derivative

Comment: Assume the second derivative $f^{\prime\prime}$ is continuous. Suppose there is an isolated value of $x$ at which the graph of $f$ changes concavity. Then the first derivative $f^\prime$ will have a local minimum or local maximum at $x$.